# JS RegEx find and replace all html links in one line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a little hard time to make regex in js to find, extract and replace all html link tags to plain text links.

My JS looks like this:

```
var str = value.replace(/<a .*href="([^\'\"]+).*?<\/a>/g, "$1");
```

This is the `value` string I have:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">clicdk here</a> Text to keep! <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">click ffhere</a>
```

This is what I expect to get:
`http://google.com Text to keep! http://facebook.com`

This is what I get:
`http://facebook.com`

It works fine if you put a second link from new line, but the problem is that I have the string without any new lines.

Please see my non-working regex example [here](https://regex101.com/r/GSskZd/1).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is notoriously hard, since html isn't a regular language.Depending on the rest of the HTML structure and what you'll do with the info you extract from those links, it might be easier to just create a documentFragment() and then select all the hyperlinks with querySelectorAll() and then returning their href and innerHTML. Do you have more information about why you need to parse a HTML string with regex and what'll happen after?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = value.replace(/<a *href="([^\'\"]+).*?<\/a>/g, "$1");
```

Try it. See regex example [here](https://regex101.com/r/GSskZd/2).

If your string like this :

```
 <a class='ss' href="http://google.com" target="_blank">clicdk here</a> Text to keep! <a class='ss' href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">click ffhere</a>
```

then Try this

```
var str = value.replace(/<a .*? *href="([^\'\"]+).*?<\/a>/g, "$1");
```

See regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/vVUnUM/2).

Comment: thank you, Khushali. But how would i now ignore if i have any attributes specified in before href? Like this - https://regex101.com/r/GSskZd/3